# When will a monad satisfy Moggi’s “equalizer” property?

Tags: ct.category-theory, universal-algebra, universal-property

I’m interested in finding when ($V$)-monads will satisfy the universal property that $\eta$ equalizes $\eta_T, T\eta$. I’m particularly interested in the case for monads on presheaf categories or that arise from morphism of limit theories.

Comment: You mean "$\eta$ is the equalizer of ... " ? because $\eta$ always equalize $\eta T$ and $T \eta$, that's part of the definition of a monad... Also the question seem too vague.

Comment: Thanks, I think I need to add a bit more context. I am fairly sure there is a class of monads where this property does not hold, for example the powerset monad or the monad arising from a degenerate Lawvere theory.

Comment: It's not really the monad that has this property but the category: it's not difficult to construct a new category that has it. See for example my www.paultaylor.eu/ASD/sobsc Also, this condition was observed long before Moggi.

Comment: Thank you for directing me to your work on Abstract Stone Duality, that’s just the sort of material I was hoping to find!